# Python lists of nested dictionaries

Tags: python

initially i had to create a function that receives the person's attributes and returns a structure that looks like that:

```
Team:
    Name: Real Madrid
    President:
        Name: Florentino Perez
        Age: 70
        Country: Spain
        Office: 001
    Coach: 
        Name: Carlo Ancelotti
        Age: 55
        Country: Italy
        Office: 006
        Coach License: 456789545678
    Players:
        - Name: Cristiano Ronaldo
          Age: 30
          Country: Portugal
          Number: 7
          Position: Forward
          Golden Balls: 1
        - Name: Chicharito
          Age: 28
          Country: Mexico
          Number: 14
          Position: Forward
        - Name: James Rodriguez
          Age: 22
          Country: Colombia
          Number: 10
          Position: Midfielder
        - Name: Lucas Modric
          Age: 28
          Country: Croatia
          Number: 19
          Position: Midfielder
```

This structure also contains info about other clubs . I managed to do this with the following function:

```
def create_person(name, age, country, **kwargs):
    info={"Name": name, "Age": age, "Country": country}
    for k,v in kwargs.iteritems():
        info[k]=v

    return info
```

I used this function to create a list of nested dictionaries and display the right structure for each team. Example:

```
teams = [
    {
        "Club Name": "Real Madrid",
        "Club President": create_person("Florentino Perez", 70, "Spain", Office="001"),
        "Club's Coach": create_person("Carlo Angelotii", 60, "Italy", Office="006", CoachLicense="456789545678"),
        "Players": {
            "Real_Player1": create_person("Cristiani Ronaldo", 30, "Portugal", Number="7", Position="Forward", GoldenBalls="1"),
            "Real_Player2": create_person("Chicharito", 28, "Mexic", Number="14", Position="Forward"),
            "Real_Player3": create_person("James Rodriguez", 22, "Columbia", Number="10", Position="Midfilder"),
            "Real_Player4": create_person("Lucas Modric", 28, "Croatia", Number="19", Position="Midfilder")
            }
        },
    {
        "Club Name": "Barcelona",
        "Club President": create_person("Josep Maria Bartolomeu", 60, "Spain", Office="B123"),
        "Club's Coach": create_person("Luis Enrique Martinez", 43, "Spain", Office="B405", CoachLicense="22282321231"),
        "Players": {
            "Barcelona_Player1": create_person("Lionel Messi", 28, "Argentina", Number="10", Position="Forward", GoldenBalls="3"),
            "Barcelona_Player2": create_person("Xavi Hernandez", 34, "Spain", Number="6", Position="Midfilder"),
            "Barcelona_Player3": create_person("Dani Alvez", 28, "Brasil", Number="22", Position="Defender"),
            "Barcelona_Player4": create_person("Gerard Pique", 29, "Spain", Number="22", Position="Defender")
            }
        }
    ]
```

Everything fine so far.

The part where I got stuck is this: Create a function print_president that receives the team name prints the following output:

Team: Real Madrid
President: Florentino Perez
Age: 70
Country: Spain
Office: 001

I could use a variable to display this but i need a function and I don't know how to work around this. Please help!

Comment: possible duplicate of [python functions and dictionaries](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26831828/python-functions-and-dictionaries)

Answer (score 1):

When you're trying to solve a problem (or ask a question) first simplify as much as you can. Your `print_president()` function takes a team name and then prints various pieces of information about the team. Each team is a dictionary with various attributes. So a simplified version of the problem might look like this:

```
teams = [
    {
        'name': 'Real Madrid',
        'pres': 'Florentino',
    },
    {
        'name': 'Barcelona',
        'pres': 'Josep',
    },
]

def print_president(team_name):
    for t in teams:
        # Now, you finish the rest. What should we check here?
        ...

print_president('Barcelona')
```

Comment: check for the president associated with the team's name..?!

Comment: @RaduAndrei If `team_name` equals `t['name']`, print some stuff.

Answer (score 0):

I can't think of a way to do this with just a team name, as you will have to know which dict to look at. I think something like this:

```
def print_president(team):
    print 'Team: {team} President: {president} Age: {age} Country: {country} Office: {office}'.format(
        team=team['Club Name'],
        president=team['Club President']['Name'],
        age=team['Club President']['Age'],
        country=team['Club President']['Country'],
        office=team['Club President']['Office']
    )
```

If you are thinking of looking through all the teams in the list, then pass in two arguments: teams_list and team_name:

```
def print_president(teams_list,team_name):
    for team in teams_list:
        if team_name in team.values():
            print 'Team: {team} President: {president} Age: {age} Country: {country} Office: {office}'.format(
                team=team['Club Name'],
                president=team['Club President']['Name'],
                age=team['Club President']['Age'],
                country=team['Club President']['Country'],
                office=team['Club President']['Office']
            )
```